# XPath query with incasesensitive

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an XML like this

```
<Authors>
<Author name='Some Author'>
<Book>B1</Book>
<Book>B2</Book>
<Book>B3</Book>
</Author>
</Authors>
```

I want to do xpath query on this xml by using Book and display the author name, and the xpath query should be with out case sensitive.

I tried to use

`Author[translate(Book,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='b1'`

But this query returns value only if i am querying with b1. if the query is with b2 or b3 it is returning null.

I am doing this in java:

```
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(
      "Authors/Author[translate(Book,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'," +
      "'abcd‌​efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='b2']");
ret_nodelist = (NodeList) xPathExpression.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: can you post the code you are using?

Comment: XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile("Authors/Auothor[translate(Book,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='b2");
ret_nodelist = (NodeList) xPathExpression.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `translate` function operates on strings, so it first coerces it's arguments to strings and then translates the result. `Book` in the context you're using it there is a node set of three nodes, and the string value of a node set is the value of its *first member*, so your expression as a whole means "find all Authors whose first Book child is b1 (case insensitive)".

Instead you need something like

```
Author[Book[translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='b1']]
```

"Find all Authors that have *any* Book child whose value is b1 (case insensitive)"